# Spring + Hibernate + Maven: jCannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/test'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I have my mysql-connector jar in:

1.) Tomcat Server lib

2.) Build Path as an External JAR.
* Removed from Maven dependency, although it remains with the same error.

**jdbc.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/test
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=****
```

**web.xml** adding it with a snippet:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/test</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And my complete **servlet-context.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springsecudev.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springsecudev.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springsecudev.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springsecudev.dao" />

<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="configLocation">
        <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="configurationClass">
        <beans:value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>   

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<interceptors>
    <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>
</interceptors>

<beans:bean id="encoder"  
class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="12"></beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

I also added the **context.xml** in META-INF to be sure I tried this one as well with

```
<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource  name="jdbc/test" 
        username="root" 
        password="root" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" 
        maxIdle="30" 
        maxWait="10000"
        initialSize="1"/>
```

But still no luck, it also has the same error being:

> INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@39c45c72: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,transactionManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,encoder,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@31e0a986
>   WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
>   ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/test'
>   WARN : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection metadata
>   java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/test'
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2160)....... [ shortened ] **Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver**
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
>       ... 40 more

I've been trying to find out what could be the problem wherein I have copied the jar in build path and server lib.

Comment: Post your maven content as well. It seems that mysql driver is missing in your maven dependencies.

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is to call 'mvn install' and it is supposed to generate your war. Now open it with Winrar or something (or just extract it) and see whether the mysql connector jar really resides in WEB-INF/lib. The chances are that its really missing.

Comment: Why are you adding he JNDI stuff? You are just using al local datasource not a JNDI one. The error states that the driver isn't found hence it isn't part of your war (not in WEB-INF/lib) or not in your tomcat. I.e. it isn't found. Add it as dependency to your pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you're missing the colon in file `jdbc.properties` for the database URL.

```
jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/test
```

I think it should be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```